# phonegap 2.2 and facebook integration

Tags: iphone, facebook, cordova, web, social-networking

I have been recently begin working with phonegap and I notice that there is no tutorial for phonegap 2.2, the most recent version. What's more, since phonegap 2.0 there has apparently been drastic changes. I am having lots of trouble with using phonegap since I am new to web-iphone apps.

I am trying to make an application with phonegap to use facebook log in to get your data (pics, friends, etc) and then post on your facebook page, update status, etc. Basically a social App.

It seems that no tutorial is clear on any facebook-phonegap integration and social web based app.

I have seen a video with phonegap 1.8 tutorial and have followed it very close, only to get many errors.

I followed the one on:
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

and have had  protocol.

I have tried many different things, but it seems that xcode simply is not able to recognize some functions or protocols. I am looking to see if I missed anything, but Ive added everything according to steps followed.
Ive tried adding the facebook.Framework, the extra headers, heck, Ive even added all of the files from the facebook SDK in the src file of the package:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

I cant seem to put together a simple facebook log in app...
anyone got it to work? what are the exact steps to follow? Im good with a new 2.2 cordova project and up until I put the files: FacebookCOnnectPlugin.h and .m that is where everything gets messed up.

I DO have the libsqlite3.0.dylib and HAVE followed the steps, added all the stuff in various .plist and all these weird long and annoying procedures many times...
Ive tried adding various libraries and just can't come up with anything else so why can't I just start a simple cordova project and get the option to log-in connect fb. like a simple hackbook sample.... I get it working in Objective-c demo (new single view application project)... Why does everything have to be so difficult and not working. I just want to get a page to start coding at. Just to get to this point, not even starting is so difficult.

very frustrating....

any help is much appreciated.

-- Im new to web apps and iphone...

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but there are lots of issues and tweaks you need to do in order for it to fully work.

In my experience `PhoneGap` Plugins do work but you have to play around a lot. E.g. I know for sure the new `Facebook SDK` is not supported by the PhoneGap plugin. Even if you import the `Deprecated Headers`. I had to use the older version of the SDK. And also with version `2.7` not all plugins are supported so I had to stick to an older version `2.5` so I could get my project to work.

Even tough I got this plugin to work on `iOS`, it doesn't work on `Android`. It's a really good platform to develop on if you're looking for fast productivity but i'm still a bit spectacle on being heavily dependant on the plugins which are not being maintained continuously.

Hope this helps.